# PHP function returning null on Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have an Ajax Call when tab is clicked in bootstrap 3.0

Below is the JS code

```
$('[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function (e) {   
   var $this = $(this);
   loadtab = $this.attr('href');
   if(loadtab=="#odhis"){
        var email = $("#email");
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "../orders.php",
              data: {'email':email.val()},
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(response){
               console.log(response);
              },
              error: function(xhr, status, error){
               console.log(xhr.responseText);
              }
       });
    }
});
```

PHP file `orders.php`

```
function getCustomOrderHistory(array $data){
    $cstm = array();
    if( !empty( $data ) ){  
        $trimmed_data = array_map('trim', $data);
        $mail = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['email'] );
        $checktable = "SELECT * from `orders` WHERE csmail='$mail'";
        $resultcstm = mysqli_query($this->_con, $checktable);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultcstm)){
            $cstm[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $cstm;
}
```

Now, when i `print_r($cstm)` then it prints the results in PHP file.
but in JS success response is empty.

Any help please?

Comment: Return 'json_encode($cstm)' in php and check

Comment: where did you call `getCustomOrderHistory` method in orders.php ?

Comment: @jitendrapurohit . i used this also.. but in vain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `dataType: "json"`, instead of `return` just encode the `$cstm` array and `echo` it, like this:

```
function getCustomOrderHistory(array $data){
    $cstm = array();
    if( !empty( $data ) ){  
        $trimmed_data = array_map('trim', $data);
        $mail = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['email'] );
        $checktable = "SELECT * from `orders` WHERE csmail='$mail'";
        $resultcstm = mysqli_query($this->_con, $checktable);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultcstm)){
            $cstm[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $json = json_encode($cstm);
    echo $json;
}
```

Comment: but if i will echo then the results will be shown in Network tan and that is something o do not want..

Comment: @Gags Then how are you planning to use the return value of `getCustomOrderHistory()` function? Since you have specified `dataType: json`, it means you're expecting a json object as server response. Hence at some point you have to encode the array and echo it so that it could be available in `success` function.

Comment: i was planning to store the function value in a variable and loop through it.... i can change data type json to plain :)